# Trying to to access FTP from EC2 that supports only Active Mode

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, ftp

I am trying to access a outside FTP using Active Mode from my Amazon EC2 instance (centos 7) (FTP only support Active)

I tried using PHP ftp commands (ftp_connect) or Codeigniter 3.0 ftp commands both setting Passive mode to false, but it fails to retrieve files after connection so i guess its not Amazon security rules problem, since it does connect, but doesn't retrieve files

Any help would be appropriated as i run out of options ...

Answer (score 2):

FTP is an old protocol that uses multiple ports to send and receive data. Its also not very friendly to NAT which is used heavily in AWS.

In active mode the server initiates a connection back to the client (This is unusual for most protocols) and is the reason why NAT can cause an issue. With AWS you should have 1:1 NAT mapping so as long as its trying to connect to the public IP NAT wont be a problem.

Making sure the correct ports are open to the FTP server is going to be required however. Which appears to be at least 20-21 and possibly a range greater than 1024.

Comment: Hello Datasage, you said "With AWS you should have 1:1 NAT mapping" is it something i need to configure my self? Regrading ports i opened all ports in my security group from 1 to 65k inbound and outbound for the purpose of making it work.

Comment: No, you don't need to configure NAT, but you do need to be aware that it exists. The IP address assigned to your network interface is always a private one. But a public IP may be mapped to your instance as well. It used to be all instances had a public ip and private ip, but due to changes with VPC, all instances have private ips, but may not have public ips.